# django template url from another app

Tags: django, django-templates

I have to be missing something silly. I have a {% url  %} in a template where the action is from another app.  It isn't working but I have no clue if there is something different about using view functions from other apps or if I am just doing something silly.

call/template/call/file.html

```
    <form action="{% url 'upload_image' %}"></form>
```

picture/urls.py

```
from .views import PictureList, PictureCreate, PictureDetail, PictureUpdate, PictureDelete, upload_image

...
url(r'^upload_image/$', upload_image, name='upload_image'),
...
```

picture/view.py

```
def upload_image( request ):
    print 'IN IMAGE UPLOAD'
    print request
```

All I ever get is:

```
NoReverseMatch at /call/4/

Reverse for 'upload_image' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: Is the file intentionally named `url.py` or is it a typo?

Comment: it was a typo...fixed now

Comment: What if you use a namespaced version `{% url 'picture:upload_image' %}` instead?

Comment: I tried `action="{% url 'picture:upload_image' %}"` and `url(r'^upload_image/$', upload_image, namespace='picture', name='upload_image'),` but says picture is not a registered namespace. (I haven't used namespaces before.)

Comment: oh, or is the namespace go in the project urls.py list (and not in picture/urls.py)

Comment: ah, got it.  namespaces are defaulted to the app name.  that worked. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 19):

When calling `reverse()` on an URL that comes from a different application, you should use its "namespaced" version, like so:

```
{% url 'app_name:app_url' %}
```

In your specific case, that translates to:

```
{% url 'picture:upload_image' %}
```