# Managing django urls

Tags: python, html, django, url

I am making a personal site. I have a blog page(site.com/blog), where I have a list of my blog posts. If I want to check a blog post simple enough I can click it and the code:

```
        <a href="/blog/{{ obj.id }}"><h1>{{ obj.topic_title }}</h1></a>
```

will get me there. Also if I want to go to my contacts page (site.com/contacts). Easy enough I click nav contacs button and I go there

```
                    <a href="/contacts">Contacts</a>
```

but if I enter a blog post (*site.com/blog/1*), I am using the same template and if I want to go to my contacts page I have to yet again click the

```
                    <a href="/contacts">Contacts</a>
```

link, but that will port me to a 404 page *site.com/blog/contacts* . How do I deal with this problem without harcoding every single page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in Django [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag, which takes the view name and returns an absolute path to it.

> Returns an absolute path reference (a URL without the domain name) matching a given view and optional parameters.

You can give it a view name and any of its view parameters as well. This is much better than how you link to the blog page:

```
{% url 'blog-view-name' obj.id %}
```

This ensures that if you ever change the structure of your views, it will still not break your links.

Comment: Can you please send somekind of a resourse, I did not quite understand what you meant

Comment: @Harton I linked the Django documentation in my answer, which should put you on the right track.

Comment: ok, so in my contacts page I have this *def index(request):
 return render(request, "contacts/contacts.html")* which works perfectly fine for the page but if in another app I have the some view name (index) things will get messy ?

Comment: @Harton See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812980/django-template-url-from-another-app): you can use the format `{% url app_name:view_name %}` More information about this is at the end of the `url` documentation I linked to.