# NoReverseMatch django - not a valid view function or pattern

Tags: python, django

Currently using Django 1.11. I get an exception of

```
Reverse for 'book_details' not found. 'book_details' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/library/book/c7311ecf-eba7-4e9d-8b1a-8ba4e075245a/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
```

I want to use the `get_absolute_url` from my Model in the details page to go to a Update page.  When I take out the reference to the .id and use the get_absolute_url.  I checked to see the name "book_details" is referenced properly. I can go to the page and have books details render properly. In the admin console of Django, the "view on site" button also does not render properly it shows this localhost:8000/admin/r/13/c7311ecf-eba7-4e9d-8b1a-8ba4e075245a/  so it does not get the library/books either

current
`<a href =" {{ book.id }}/update">Update</a>`

desired
`<a href =" {{ book.get_absolute_url }}/update">Update</a>`

Where have I mistyped for this to not work?

---

Setup in files:

Yes, I do have UUID as the primary key.

In `views.py`

```
class BookDetailsView(generic.DetailView):
"""
Generic class-based detail view for a Book.
"""
model = Book
```

in `urls.py`

```
url(r'^book/(?P<pk>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})$', views.BookDetailsView.as_view(), name='book_details'),
url(r'^book/(?P<pk>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})/update/$', views.BookUpdate.as_view(), name='book_update'),
```

in `models.py`

class Book(models.Model):

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    """Returns the URL of the book for details"""
    return reverse('book_details', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Comment: The error message clearly references `'audition_details'`, but none of the code you have shown us includes that string. We can't troubleshoot what we can't see. However, note that `<a href="{{ foo }}/bar">` is a code smell. Consider using [the `url` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url), which provides "a way to output links without violating the DRY principle by having to hard-code URLs in your templates".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the `url` tag. After I figured out the proper way to call URLs in the name spaces, I replaced my `/update` with a the correct URL generation.

Answer (score 1):

Try providing the `pk` as keyword argument to the `reverse` function,

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('book_details', kwargs={ 'pk': str(self.id) })
```

Also, you are missing a trailing slash at the end of the url,

```
url(r'^book/(?P<pk>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})/$', views.BookDetailsView.as_view(), name='book_details'),
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. This helped, but did not resolve the issue. I looked closer at the stack and found the call back was trying to access the urls.py in another app. After adding the namespace to the call, it worked `library:book_details`   I found some references that helped me out [source1](http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2016/01/06/django-how-to-reverse-urls-belonged-to-other-apps) [source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812980/django-template-url-from-another-app)

Comment: I forgot to mention the namespace buddy, glad you figured it out yourself. Keep up the good work.

Comment: What I was also missing "namespace". Solved the issue. Thanks !